# How can I escape a right-curly brace ( } ) in a directory name of a WMI Win32_Directory query?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, wql

I'm trying to execute a WMI query that lists all the subdirectories in a directory on a different network-attached computer (server), but it's failing with a `System.Management.ManagementException` "Invalid query" exception.

I am practically certain that this issue is due to the directory name containing left- and/or right-curly braces (`{`, `}`).

**UPDATE:** I've determined that the issue is not the left-curly brace, but the right-curly brace.

I've tried various things to escape these characters, but nothing seems to work.

Below is a contrived example that fails with "Invalid query" every time.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string username = @"Domain\User";
        const string password = @"Password";
        const string server = @"Server";

        const string query = @"Associators of {"
                             + @"Win32_Directory.Name='"
                             + @"c:\program files (x86)\a_test}"
                             + @"'} "
                             + @"Where AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory ResultRole = PartComponent";

        var options = new ConnectionOptions { Username = username, Password = password };
        var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + server + @"\root\cimv2", options);
        var wmiQuery = new ObjectQuery(query);
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, wmiQuery);
        var searchResults = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var searchResult in searchResults)
        {
            var subPath = searchResult.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
            var system = Convert.ToBoolean(searchResult.GetPropertyValue("System"));
            Console.WriteLine($"subPath = {subPath}; system = {system}");
        }
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, the code is running on a Windows 10 machine querying a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 server (yes, it's scheduled for demolition).

Thanks!

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827199/escaping-strings-when-using-wmic) help?

Comment: @vasily.sib - The question you point suggests escaping with a caret (`^`) character.  I've tried escaping the curly braces with back slash, forward slash, another curly brace, caret (`^`) - none work.

Comment: its looks like that you have extra closing brackets ( **}** ) , try to comment out the 3rd row in your query:  `+ @"'} "`

Comment: @styx - those are there to escape the curly braces from C# string interpolation.

Comment: If you 'unfold' your query you get `Associators of {Win32_Directory.Name='c:\program files (x86)\a_test}'} Where AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory ResultRole = PartComponent` and as you can see you have 1 opening brackets and 2 closing brackets

Comment: @styx...that `}` at the end of `a_test}` is last character of the name of that directory.  It is the very character that I'm attempting to escape.  So, there are no unbalanced brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a quirk of the `Associators of` parsing. To fix this, use the double quote syntax for strings rather than the single quote syntax (taking care to escape backslashes, since this is required for the double quote approach):

```
const string query = @"Associators of {"
                     + @"Win32_Directory.Name="""
                     + @"c:\\program files (x86)\\a_test}"
                     + @"""} "
                     + @"Where AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory ResultRole = PartComponent";
```

Comment: Thank you!  I felt very strongly that this had to be a parsing bug, but couldn't get anything to work!

Comment: Quick followup question: What if both } and "are present in a Associators query? Such as in ObjectIDs of MSFT_VirtualDisk objects. How to quote the " ? Great answer :)

Comment: @JohannesThoma: I suspect escaping the double quotes with a backslash (`\"`) should work (but I can't test at the moment).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thank you yes the backslash worked. So preparing for quoting can be done with `string quoted_object_id = vdisk["ObjectId"].ToString().Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"""", @"\""");` (vdisk being a MSFT_VirtualDisk object)